# E: Unable to locate package gnome-schedule

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install crontab but it is showing E:
I am unable to locate package gnome-schedule even though i wrote 'sudo apt-get update' and pressed enter it is not working.
I mean the cron tab is not installing.